# Headphone jack disabled in windows, after using Ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, sound, windows, headphones

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Alienware M15x-R1 and love it, but whenever I properly shut down or reboot from within Ubuntu, when I access Windows my headphone jack doesn't work, it reads headphones are plugged in but it doesn't send sound, essentially it's muted. This wasn't happening before Ubuntu. The jack works fine in Ubuntu. All drivers are updated.

When I manually force shut down with my power button, the headphone works, so Ubuntu is somehow muting my jack when shutting down. Is there anyway to prevent this or not allow Ubuntu access to Windows privileges? Something? I love Ubuntu and plan on continuing to use it, but manually shutting down each time is going to be a pain and is really only a temporary solution, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a full and fool-proof solution that I can offer, but I do know that this happens with some hardware, where the headphone jack sense is "muted" by ALSA.

To turn it back on, you can use `alsamixer`:

[image]

My screenshot does not display the option for headphone jack sense because my card does not support it, but it is similar to the S/PDIF option. Select it with your keyboard <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> and press <kbd>M</kbd> to mute or unmute it. These settings should stick with the system even when you reboot.

Depending on your sound card configuration, it may also be another option in ALSA's configuration that causes the problem, so if it doesn't work, be sure to look for any suspect features. You can also expand on your problem in your question (with a screenshot of your sound card options from `alsamixer` if this doesn't work, and I'll see if I can give an update to my answer.